# Constraint with scipy

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, constraints, minimize

I have a problem of multi-objective optimization under constraint (maximization), in fact I transformed it into a mono-objective problem via the weighting technique and I added 2 variable x1, x2 (to optimize) with a constraint `0 <x1 + x2 <1` so their sum must be strictly less than 1 to give rise to the 3rd objective function as described in the code below.

When I execute the sum is always greater than 1.

```
    for i in range(len(f1)):
        def f(x):
            x1= x[0]
            x2= x[1]
            return -(x1*f1[i]+ x2*f2[i]+ (1-x1-x2)*f3[i])

        def constraint(x):
            return x[0]+x[1]-1

        b= (0.2, 0.8)
        bnds= (b, b)
        x0=[0.5,0.4]

        cons= ({'type': 'ineq','fun':constraint})

        res = minimize(f,x0, method= 'SLSQP', bounds=bnds, constraints=cons)

        print('Vect_ponderation : ', res.x)
```

Output:

```
Vect_ponderation :  [0.8 0.8]
Vect_ponderation :  [0.8 0.8]
Vect_ponderation :  [0.8 0.8]
Vect_ponderation :  [0.8 0.8]
```

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) says:

> Equality constraint means that the constraint function result is to be zero **whereas inequality means that it is to be non-negative**. Note that COBYLA only supports inequality constraints.

```
def constraint(x):
    return x[0] + x[1] -1
```

means:

```
x0 + x1 - 1 >= 0  # non-negative
<-> 
x0 + x1 >= 1
```

which is respected in your solution.

You probably want:

```
def constraint(x):
    return - x[0] - x[1] + 1
```

Also keep in mind, that there is no concept of *strict inequality*. You will need to introduce some *epsilon* constant a-priori like: `eps = 1e-6`:

```
def constraint(x):
    return - x[0] - x[1] + 1 - EPS
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, your problem is that the output has `x1+x2>1`. I've checked [optimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html) documentation and it says: 'inequality means that it is to be non-negative'. Thus, you have requested something opposite to what you think you have requested.

Suggestions:

- You have very simple function, so try providing jacobian as an additional parameter. The fit is much more efficient then.
- Try to present [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). This makes answering much easier. Your question lacks `f1`, `f2`, and `f3` definitions.
- Try to ask a question. I've found something that might be the problem you're trying to solve, but I'm not sure because there is no question (i.e., sentence with question mark) in your question.